# I need to run a win32 executable which I do not trust. Is there any free online service / sandbox which could do it for me?

Tags: sandbox

I need to run a win32 executable which I do not trust. Is there any free online service which could do it for me?

Comment: See my question about this same topic. http://superuser.com/questions/83561/safely-view-websites-that-may-be-harmful

Comment: Why does it have to be online? Don't you just need A solution?

Comment: Do you need to interact with the running program, or just find out whether is it malicious?

Answer (score 8):

You could install something like [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/).

I don't know of any online equivalent - I'm not sure it's even possible.

Answer (score 7):

I try out all of my experimental software in a virtual machine before installing to my workstation.

- [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/)
- [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/)

Answer (score 3):

[Cameyo](http://www.cameyo.com/default.aspx) has an online application virtualization system which creates a standalone sandboxed version from an uploaded installer.